# Como tirar quebra de linha no "Cin" da biblioteca <iostream>?

Tags: c++, entrada-de-dados

Como posso tirar a quebra de linha ao ler alguma variável com `cin`?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int dia, mes, ano;
    cout<< "Data: ";
    cin>> dia;cout<<"/";  cin>> mes;cout<<"/";  cin>> ano;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Compilado:
[image: Resultado]

Eu quero que fique assim:
[image: Como deve ser]

Comment: Seria interessante você postar o código ao invés da imagem do código. Assim você aumenta o interesse das pessoas a lhe ajudar.

Comment: Coloque esse código no lugar da PRIMEIRA imagem.

Comment: Está perfeito! Ficará mais fácil para alguém lhe ajudar agora.

Comment: prontinho, eu só quero que quando o "cin" ler o valor não pular uma linha ou seja continuar na mesma linha

Comment: Evitar a quebra de linha com `cin` não é possível. Ou lé tudo como uma `string` e faz parse de cada parte da data ou implementa uma leitura baseada em `getch`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é possível. O `cin` é feito para uso básico, para experimentação, interação mínima sem cerimônia. Se deseja ter controle total sobre a entrada de dados terá que escrever um código que faça o controle da forma que deseja, o que não é simples fazer certo. C++ não é uma linguagem que entrega tudo pronto e é raro ter bibliotecas externas que não sejam muito genéricas.